# Python Flask add url while running

Tags: python-2.7, rest, web, flask

I'm making an application with flask but is there any way to add a new URL while Flask is running?
Just like 
127.0.0.1/app/testfunction -> this one is registered but when i surf to this its need to generate a new random URL.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is called [add_url_rule](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule).

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    pass
```

Is equivalent to the following:

```
def index():
    pass
app.add_url_rule('/', 'index', index)
```

app.route calls `add_url_rule` internally. For more information check out their docs.

Comment: is it then possible to add this to a registerd blueprint?

Comment: Yes, it's the same for a blueprint. [Blueprint.add_url_rule](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Blueprint.add_url_rule)

Comment: this is the line what i do: app.add_url_rule("/test",methods=["GET"], view_func=test)               then i get a function that called test